# Modify visual studio's SQL Express Bootstrapper

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, sql-server-express, bootstrapper

I know there are ways of installing SQL Express from the command line. [This link gives an example of that.](http://blogesh.wordpress.com/2008/09/23/silent-install-of-sql-server-2008/) There is another example [in here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx).

When I make this change in my application:

[image]

then when I deploy my application and install it on a computer that does not have that prerequisite I notice that the installer downloads that prerequisite:

[image]

If I cancel the installation and then launch the exe file that the installer downloaded then I will see:

[image]

If I do not cancel the installer, I believe that the installer then goes ahead and installs SQL Server Express with a technique similar to the one posted by the first two links [link 1](http://blogesh.wordpress.com/2008/09/23/silent-install-of-sql-server-2008/), [link 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx).

Where does Visual Studio stores the parameters that are being passed to the exe that it downloads in order to create a silent install? will it be possible to modify those parameters that are being passed to the exe? also I know which file (prerequisites) did visual studio (installer) downloads because I found it on the computer when installing my application but how can I tell from what link does visual studio downloads the prerequisites? I know it depends on the OS version and architecture of the operating system where the application is being installed.

Anyways I am just curious about the last paragraph. In short, I just want to modify the parameters that are being passed to the prerequisites of SQL Server Express 2008. Those parameters should be somewhere in the application that I deployed. Or maybe they get downloaded from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a 64-bit machine the SQL Server Express bootstrapper is typically located in the following folder:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\SqlExpress2008\en`

Look inside the package.xml file for the command line parameters for the installer.

Comment: I guess I will be able to change some parameters in there. I will like to enable tcp ip remote connections when installing SQL server 2008 express. It will be nice if I can tell visual studio which XML file to use. Anyways that was of great help... Thanks a lot

Comment: You can just make a copy of the entire SqlExpress2008 folder and change the product name to something like "Customized SQL Server 2008 Express". Visual Studio will pick it up. This way you will be able to chose original or customized installation as your prerequisite.